# Why aren't my firestore function triggers fire in local emulators when data changes?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm playing around with the new firebase emulator suite and I'm trying to use the functions and firestore emulators combined to do full functional testing of my firebase functions using Jest. I've got a firebase function defined like this

```
exports.sendNewUserNotification = functions.firestore
  .document(`users/{userId}`)
  .onCreate(() => console.log("I was called!"));
```

And then in my test suite I create a user like so

```
import * as firebase from "@firebase/testing";

process.env.FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST = "localhost:8080";

const testUser = {
  isManager: false,
  id: "12345"
};

const PROJECT_ID = `testproject${Date.now()}`;

const app = firebase.initializeAdminApp({
  projectId: PROJECT_ID
});

describe("sendUserNotification tests", () => {
  it("should invoke the function for manager", async done => {
    await app
      .firestore()
      .collection("users")
      .doc(testUser.id)
      .set(testUser);
    const user = await app
      .firestore()
      .collection("users")
      .doc(testUser.id)
      .get();
    console.log(user.data()); // <-- User exists here, but trigger never fires
    done();
  });
});
```

I have verified that the test app is pointing at the local emulator and the [firebase docs say the emulator should support firestore triggers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator#cloud_firestore).

Comment: What's in `../../repos/FirestoreUserRepo/FirestoreUserRepo`?

Comment: @DougStevenson The type definition for User and a wrapper around the firebase admin sdk with all of the operations I take on the user collection in my app. I've done that with all my firestore entities so that I can test them more easily and isolate my dependencies better. I've got integration tests working with all of those and the firestore emulator that I'm pretty pleased with.

Comment: Could you edit the question to show the contents of that file?  We need to be able to see everything involved.  It's even better if you can distill the example down to a MCVE.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I've completely removed the repo from the example as it's not really necessary to reproduce. I'll see about creating an example repo tomorrow.

Comment: Also consider posting an issue to the firebase-tools github with a bug report if you think you've followed all the instructions.  https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been doing the same thing, but with one big difference. I use the firebase-admin SDK and not the @firebase/testing.

According to the documentation you can use the firebase-admin SDK against the emulator.

I've created a set if jest tests using the firebase-admin SDK and they do trigger my firestore triggers.

Try the same but using the firebase-admin SDK